# Adjusting the length of a character leg and arm

Tags: measurement

I want to know if it is possible to adust specific parts of a character by inserting measurements. For example, i want to be able to change the length and thickness of a character arm by inserting measurements like 9.3 inches/centimeters for the length of the character arm and it will adjust to that length and the same thing for the thickness

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that directly in Blender unless you use addons.  I am not familiar enough with the available addons to recommend one, but I do know that [MB-Lab](https://mblab.dev/about/) is an addon that gives you some control over such measurements and have used it.

You can do it in many third party character generator applications.  I use [MakeHuman Community edition](http://www.makehumancommunity.org/) for this purpose and can recommend it.

Both are open source. Both have ways to automatically generate armatures for the character. I believe that MB-Lab is limited to modifications *before* you finalize the character and can make changes afterwards.  You can configure MakeHuman either way but it is difficult to make changes once you've parented the character to an armature.

Other commercial external character generators include Daz and Poser. You can find more by searching for terms like *full body character creator* with your favorite search engine.